# What is the term for the quality of a number to be prime or composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

I know this is more a question of language and philosophy than of theory, but I have not been able to find anything on this, and it's difficult to believe that the word does not exist.

The quality of a number to be even or odd is called parity. The quality of a number to be positive or negative is called sign. What is the term for the quality of a number to be prime or composite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quality of whether or not a number is prime is called [primality](https://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove1.html).

A [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) will tell whether or not a number is prime.